# Unit testing of sax parser

Tags: java, xml, unit-testing, sax

I have a legacy java-code and some sax parsing in it. I want to write unit tests for those sax parsers.

Implementation of sax parsers is simple. It's like a class that extends `DefaultHandler` and overrides some methods like `startElement` and `endElement`.

Sax parsers provide a big tree of objects since xml that they parse is huge.

When I try to write unit tests for sax parsers I get big test methods which do:

- loading test variant of XML file from resources
- asking instance of sax parser to parse that XML
- getting result of parsing
- comparing parsed object tree with expected one by asserting each field of each object in tree

As I already said XML is huge. So a get A LOT of asserts when I compare result objects.

Please suggest me something. I don't want to write such big test methods for every sax parser that my legacy code has.

Comment: Why don't you try xmlunit?

Answer (score 0):

Try this   also.

> public void testMySaxParser() throws Exception {
>       InputStream xml = getTestDocument();
>       // create a custom handler that records events and verifies them
>       // against the expected sequence of events
>       MyRecordingHandler handler = new MyRecordingHandler();
>       // tell the handler that you're about to generate the sequence of
>       // events that you expect to be repeated later by the real SAXParser
>       handler.startRecording();
>       handler.startDocument();
>       handler.startElement("", "", "root", new Attributes());
>       handler.startElement("", "", "child", new Attributes());
>       handler.characters("Some text".toCharArray(), 0, 9);
>       handler.endElement("", "", "child");
>       handler.startElement("", "", "child", new Attributes());
>       handler.characters("Some more text".toCharArray(), 0, 14);
>       handler.endElement("", "", "child");
>       handler.endElement();
>       handler.endDocument();
>       // tell the handler that the "expectations recording" is done
>       // and that it should move into the "playback" mode
>       handler.stopRecording();
>       // exercise the parser to generate the actual events to the handler
>       getSAXParser().parse(xml, handler);
>       // ask the handler object to verify that the expected events occurred
>       handler.verify();   }

Comment: It would be painful if I will write all cases this way.

Comment: Also, I believe you cannot create a new instance of Attributes as it is an abstract class?